# The new, shortened links to questions and answers don't work as targets when converting answers to comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment, short-links

Previously, when one clicked the "link" button on a question or answer, a link that was (more or less) of the form

> http:// ____.stackexchange.com/questions/questionnumber/questiontitle/postnumber#postnumber

was provided. Now, the links look like

> http:// ____.stackexchange.com/q/postnumber/userid

I'm all for shortening and simplification, but when I go to migrate an answer to a comment, the shortened links don't work as targets; I get an error message saying "target is invalid: no action taken". Instead, I have to follow the shortened link and copy the expanded url out of my browser's address bar, and use that in the "convert answer to comment" dialog.

Could this be fixed so that the shortened links can be used to migrate answers?

Not sure if this qualifies as a bug or feature request.

Comment: Another workaround is to just copy the post ID in the shortened URL.

Comment: Or just remove the `/userid` from the shortened URL.

Comment: Actually, this is only a new feature for answers, for questions the link always did give the link in this form.

Comment: I'm glad *someone* actually has the time to figure out where these answers posted as comments are supposed to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.